# Firestore call takes (on avg) 100/200 ms too long for dialogflow reponse timeout

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

I'm creating a dialogflow bot, for the fulfillment of the bot I am using a node server (on google cloud functions) to retrieve data through a function returning a promise

I've tried adding a `agent.setFollowupEvent('ExtendTimeOut');` because I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51840301/how-to-manage-the-5-seconds-response-timeout-limit-in-dialogflow-api-ai) that this would extend the timeout (of 5 secs)
but I don't really know where to put it and it doesn't seem to work.

I'm currently using the `db.collection("details").where("keywords", "array-contains", keyword)` to retrieve data from Firestore

DB Structure:

```
users
  |__> userID
         |__> user properties
         |__> [Array of keywords (ex. fifa, gta, etc)]
```

Dialogflow fulfillment function:

```
function GetUserDetails(agent) {
        var keyword = agent.parameters.any //keyword to search for

        return new Promise( function( resolve, reject ){
            db.collection("details").where("keywords", "array-contains", keyword)
            .get()
            .then(function(querySnapshot) {

                querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                    console.log("Contact data:", doc.data());
                    agent.add("these are the user details for " + doc.data()["name"]));
                    agent.add(doc.data()["username"]);
                    agent.add(doc.data()["useremail"]);

                });
                resolve()
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                reject( error );
                console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
            });

        });
}

let intentMap = new Map();
intentMap.set('GetUserDetails', GetUserDetails);;
agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
```

Does anyone know how to speed up the data retrieval or extend this timeout?

Comment: Without seeing the structure of your store and your code, it is very difficult to make suggestions. Please update your question to show what you're currently doing and some example data.

Comment: @Prisoner sorry, I've updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Two things immediately come to mind to make sure you're improving performance:

- Make sure the `keywords` field is indexed. The `array-contains` operation is expensive, and this can help.
- Consider limiting how many are returned. If there are a lot that get returned, this decreases performance dramatically (and makes for a very cluttered response).